# Does MBP and anti-glare MBP use the same top case?

Tags: macbook-pro

[image]

I am now using a 2011 MacBook Pro with anti-glare display.

I am going to replace the palm top case (The unibody case with palm, speaker and keyboard)

But I got noticed that the anti-glare display uses different top case from the regular glossy display, so I have to pay attention while buying the new top case, it that true?

I have contacted some eBay sellers, they seems not sure about this.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no top case on the unibody Mac line. The unibody is the last piece left on the workbench when you tear down a MacBook Pro.  Might you link to iFixit.com to indicate the exact part nuber you are proposing to "swap"?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, I have attached a picture on my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single difference between the Glossy and the anti glare MBP is the presence of a glass panel on the glossy one.

So yes they use the same body.